# Finding values of x that gives a specific slope on a tangent on a curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

"For the function $f$ it is the case that $f(x) = x^4 - 18x^2$. For which values of $x$ does the graph to the function have a tangent with the slope = 15?"

This is how I did it: Since we're dealing with a tangent of a curve, and its slope, this means that I should take the derivative of this function. E.g. if the slope of the curve on the point $x_t = 5$ then the tangent to that point on the curve has a slope of 5.

$f'(x) = 4x^3 - 36x$

$4x^3 - 36x = 15$

This has no real solutions. The answer in the book is: $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 3, x_3 = -3$.

Where am I going wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions that your text provided are solutions to the values of $x$ where $f'(x) = 0$, where the line tangent at those values of $x$ is horizontal, not where slope is $15$!

Note:

$$f'(x) = 4x^3 - 36x = x(2x+6)(2x - 6) = 0 \iff x = 0, \;\text{ or}\;x = \pm 3$$

You're derivative is correct, and the equation to solve, as well. The value of slope $=15$  must be a misprint in the text.

Comment: What solution is the one real one?

Comment: [see this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28+4x^3+-+36x+%3D+15%29)

Comment: @Peatherfed all three solutions are real, it's just how wa approximates numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer the book has given you tells you where the tangent has slope $0$, not $15$. Perhaps it's a misprint, or something.

The equation $4x^3-36x=15$ *does* have at least one real solution, though, since odd-degree polynomials always have at least one real zero.